# In At vs In From vs Into

Tags: word-usage, technology

For a user interface project, my group is trying to determine the correct phrasing for when an account is being used at multiple computers. There were a few different options being given, but which one most accurately describes the situation? Is there a better option we've missed?

1. "Your account is also logged into another computer." / "Your account is also logged into other computers."
   *I was against this one because the issue isn't that they're logged into the computer but that they're logged into our app from another computer.*
2. "Your account is also logged in at another computer." / "Your account is also logged in at other computers."
    
   *This one was said to be awkwardly-worded because of the "at".*
3. "Your account is also logged in from another computer." / "Your account is also logged in from other computers."
   *Seemed less awkward than 2. but not as good as 1.*

Comment: I find these all awkward because an account doesn't log in, a user does.  Maybe "The user associated with this account is also logged in on another computer"?

Comment: Your account is in use on another computer.?

Comment: @JohnD, that doesn't feel correct either because we are issuing the warning since we don't know if the user is actually the one logged in.

Comment: @geometrikal that was also cast down by some of our group because we don't know if the account is actually in use or just a residual session.

Comment: @DavidMillar I see- Presumably in order to log in one would have to have the proper credentials, so maybe "A user associated..."? If it's not a user logged in, then why would the account be active?  In any case I like geometrikal's suggestions better, maybe changed to "Your account is open/active on another computer."

Comment: **Another user has logged into your account.** **Your account has been accessed from another computer.**

Comment: @JohnD: OP is saying the account **is** logged in. Not the account **has** logged in. Only the latter would suggest that the account is the one doing the logging in.

Answer (score 2):

> Another computer is already logged into this account.

or

> Another session is using this account.

It makes much more sense to lead with the problem.  There is no problem with the account here.  Another session might be a problem, if the system allows only one active session per account or if the user was not aware that the earlier session is still active.

Answer (score 0):

Your account has been logged into from another computer at 13:30
If you logged in at this time ignore this message but if this wasn't you click the link below.
I may be wrong but hopefully this gives you a start